# Echoing every week from text file?

Tags: php, html, text

Hi so my problem here today is I am trying to have it on my website so when it hits each week a text from a text file will echo out to the website this is how the text file would look like:

> week 1
>
> week 2
>
> week 3

and it keeps on going.
so basically I am trying to make it so for example first week it will grab first line next week it will grab second line and all of the lines are stored in a text file. NOTE: I am trying to add this straight into my html code which is in a php file!!
here is my code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$text = file_get_contents("lines.txt");  
$text = trim($text); //This removes blank lines so that your 
//explode doesn't get any empty values at the start or the end.     
$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
$lineNumber = count($array);

echo "<p>{$array[0]}</p>";
?>
```

Thank You !

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: Can you use a different approach: have the HTML always include the same file, and have a different process update the file every week, so it contains only that week's contents.

Comment: @pedram I have some code but... here just look i updated it :P

Comment: @AdamLiss can you rephrase currently what i meant was i have the html in my php file so like this home.php << html inside and then i have a .txt file holding my text

Comment: as i see, you need `cron job` for this case!

Comment: Right, and you want to read a part of the `lines.txt` file into the html. But instead, why not change the `lines.txt` file each week, so it contains only the text you want to display? Then your HTML can be simple.

Comment: @pedram can you edit my code and so i can test it please